# How to reduce air inside blended drink?

Tags: drinks

I'm making a mix of protein powder, milk and coffee in the blender. When I blend it, it seems so I get a mixture which is very foamy and takes a while to settle. Anyway I can make the foamy part go away faster?

Comment: What type of blender? If it's an immersion blender, keeping the blade fully submerged makes a big difference.

Comment: [Something which looks like this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.taw9eel.com%2Fen%2Fwansa-blender-400w-1-5l-bl1009k-cb-510092.html&psig=AOvVaw08V0LNlNC2qjNV03VZWx83&ust=1685225303988000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBEQjRxqFwoTCND-rND_k_8CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAF) @dbmag9

Comment: Have you tried any alternatives to blending, such as using a shaker?

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is normal for a protein shake. It depends on the brand of protein will foam or not. But if it bothers you, you can add soy lecithin. It will be a defoamer.

Comment: Isn’t soy lecithin used to make/stabilize foams out of any liquid?